# Опечатка на главной, опечатка в знаках

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В блоке, который показывается новичкам есть странная фраза: `"Лучшие ответы получают голоса и оказываются на поднимаются в рейтинге"`.

Смотри скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще опечатка, отписывался про нее месяц назад, может не заметили:

Опечатка в "Знаках".

Знак `Популист`

```
Лучший ответ по рейтенгу, превысивший принятый ответ, с более 10 баллами, более чем в 2 раза
```

рейтенгу => рейтингу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил.

1. Стало так: «Лучшие ответы получают голоса и поднимаются вверх».
2. Стало так: «Ответ с наилучшим рейтингом, который обошёл более чем вдвое принятый ответ с рейтингом больше 10».

Новые строки появятся со следующим обновлением из Transifex'а.